# Muss das Adjektiv "einziges" groß geschrieben werden?

Tags: meaning-in-context, spelling

> Man kann Geld aber nicht nur als Tauschmittel einsetzen, sondern nutzt es auch als Wertmaßstab. Damit können Preise von Gütern in Relation zueinander gesetzt oder addiert werden. Man weiß durch Geld zum Beispiel, dass ein Liter Milch doppelt so viel kostet wie zwei **Brötchen**, und dass der Preis von vier Brötchen viermal so hoch **ist** wie der für ein **einziges**.

1. Warum steht "ist" hier nach Brötchen und nicht vor dem Komma?
   Ich vermute, dass der Satz so sein muss: "... wie zwei Brötchen ist, und dass ... Einziges ist".
2. Wird das Adjektiv klein geschrieben und das Wort "Brötchen" gelöscht, weil man es durch den Zusammenhang versteht oder ist es falsch und es muss substantiviert werden?

Comment: Man fragt sich aber auch, wieso gemessen an der Milch die Brötchen so teuer sind.

Comment: Ich frage mich auch, ob dieser Text das Papier wert ist, auf dem er steht. Wie gut, dass man Geld als Maßstab hat. Sonst käme man nie darauf, dass der Wert von vier Brötchen vier mal so hoch ist wie der eines einzigen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Zur ersten Frage: Vor dem Komma steht kein »ist«, weil »kostet« das Prädikat ist. Als Verständnishilfe kann man sich auch die entsprechende Hauptsatzkonstruktion ansehen.

> Ein Liter Milch kostet doppelt so viel wie ein Brötchen.

Auch hier wäre es grammatikalisch falsch, ein »ist« anzuhängen. Im Gegensatz dazu steht später ein »ist«, weil dort anders konstruiert wird: Dort wird gesagt, dass "der Preis ist". Analog hätte konstruieren *können*:

> Der Preis für einen Liter Milch *ist* doppelt so hoch wie der für ein Brötchen.

Zur zweiten Frage: Es liegt eine Ellipse vor; das ausgelassene Wort »Brötchen« lässt sich leicht ergänzen. Daher ist »einziges« keine Substantivierung und wird klein geschrieben. Der *Duden* dazu:

> Wenn nach einem Adjektiv ein Substantiv eingespart worden ist, das sonst noch im Text vorkommt und daher ohne Weiteres ergänzt werden kann, schreibt man klein (= attributiv-elliptischer Gebrauch) <§ 58 (1)>.
>
> - Mir gefallen alle Krawatten sehr gut. Besonders mag ich die gestreiften und die gepunkteten (= die gestreiften und gepunkteten Krawatten).
> - Sie war die aufmerksamste und klügste unter allen Zuhörerinnen.
> - Das blaue ist mein Auto.
>
> https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/Gro%C3%9F-%20und%20Kleinschreibung

Comment: also wenn man es durch Kontext verstehen kann, braucht man nicht  es wieder zu nennen

Answer (score 4):

1. "ist" bezieht sich auf den Preis. "Der Preis ist so hoch" - vs. "vier Brötchen sind so teuer wie xy".

Für zweitens habe ich keine zitierbare Regel zur Hand:

2. Ja, "einziges" bezieht sich auf Brötchen, vollständig wäre "einziges Brötchen". "wie der für ein Einziges" wäre m.E. falsch.